# how do i prove that $\check{\widehat{\left(f\right)}}=f$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I have by definition,
$$\check{\alpha}(x):=f(x)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}\alpha_{k}e^{ikx}, \ \ x \in \mathbb{R} .$$
where $\alpha=(\alpha_{k})_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{Z}) $, $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{Z})$ is the space of rapidly decreasing sequences such that
$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} |\alpha_k|<+\infty,\ \ \sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} |\alpha_k||k|^{n}<+\infty, \ \ n=1,2,...$$
I have managed to prove that $\widehat{(\check{\alpha})}=\hat{f}=\alpha$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-i\xi x}dx&=&\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}\alpha_{k}e^{ikx}e^{-i\xi x}dx\\
&\underbrace{=}_{\text{Con.uniforme}}&\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}\alpha_{k}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{ikx}e^{-i\xi x}dx\\
&=&\alpha_{\xi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{(\xi-\xi)i x} dx+ \sum_{k\neq \xi}\alpha_{k}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{(k-\xi)ix}  dx\\\\
&\underbrace{=}_{\text{Ortogonalidad (2.11)}}& \alpha_{\xi}2\pi+\sum_{k\neq \xi}\alpha_{k}(0)\\
\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-i\xi x}dx&=&\alpha_{\xi}\\
\hat{f}(\xi)&=&\underbrace{\alpha_{\xi} }_{\in \ \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{Z})}
\end{eqnarray*}
but I can't prove that $\check{\widehat{\left(f\right)}}=f$, where $f \in C_{per}^{\infty}([-\pi,\pi])$.

Comment: To be able to show this you need the definition of the coefficients $\alpha_k$, which are for a $2 \pi$ periodic function given by
\begin{align}\alpha_k\big[f\big] &:= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) e^{ikx} \mathrm d x \end{align}